# Configuration of Yii2 oci8 module

Tags: php, oci8

i am trying to connect my Yii2 project to Oracle db, i have found [this](https://github.com/apaoww/yii2-oci8) oci8 plugin for yii2 written by apaoww on github. I managed to get php oci8 extension working, and encountered i hope my last problem with the connection.
I know dbname, ip, username, password and port to connect on, but still i was not able to decrypt, where the schemaname belongs to, i probably am a complete dumba**, but i was not able to find any other examples of filling the dp.php config file, than the one on GitHub project page, which didn't really make it clear for me. My issue is, **where should i put the schemaname in this array?**

```
    'db' => [
                'class' => 'apaoww\oci8\Oci8DbConnection',
                'dsn' => 'oci8:dbname=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=127.0.0.1)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=xe)));charset=AL32UTF8;',
                'username' => 'yourdatabaseschemaname',
                'password' => 'databasepassword',
                'attributes' => []
    ],
```

Comment: Read the current value of the `username` index carefully.

Comment: I read it carefully, but i did not figure out, if i put schemaname there, where do i put the username?

Comment: The username is, effectively, the schema.  A PDO_OCI connection (that Yii2 must be doing with these values) looks like this: `new \PDO('oci:dbname=xxx;charset=yyy', 'username', 'password');`

Comment: I am not sure, what do you mean by username effectively being schema. Maybe it is caused by my lack of knowledge about Oracle RDBMS, but i dont get, how username could be name of schema.

Comment: Users and schemas are [equivalent in Oracle](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:974699100346868838).

Comment: I am the author of the extension. Yes the comment by timclutton is right. Username in MySql is equivalent to schema name in Oracle. You can put the schema name next to username array key.